# How to style different input ranges on the same site

Tags: html, css, range

I'm trying to style two different ranges on my site. The first one I've already styled. The problem is with the second one. I want the second range to be styled differently than the first one.

Here's an example of what I mean:

- Range 1: blue background
- Range 2: green background

For now, the second range keeps taking the first range's css styling so I end up with two blue ranges. I've tried using different input types (input[type=range], input[type=range2]), but it's not working. I've seen pages do this so I'm pretty sure it's possible. Do I have to use multiple stylesheets or can I do it with custom input types? I think this can be done with custom input types, in which case I'm probably doing something wrong then.

Comment: Use classes, "custom input types" isn't even a thing.

Comment: theres a name for what I mean. I call them customs.

Comment: I can't even tell if you're being serious or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to style ranges. First of all, `input[type="range"]` can only written that way and will only work with ranges, nothing more specific.

You wanted backgrounds? Here they are:

HTML

```
<input type="range" id="green">
<input type="range" id="blue">
```

CSS(where it get's tough)

```
#green::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background-color: green;
}

#green::-moz-range-track {
    background-color: green;
}

#green::-ms-track, #green::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: green;
}

#blue::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background-color: blue;
}

#blue::-moz-range-track {
    background-color: blue;
}

#blue::-ms-track, #blue::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You might be wandering why so much? styling ranges is still not very well supported.

But hey! If you still want to know more, go to https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/. I don't like it, but sure you can do it!